# Not able to load partial templates using Thymleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have **templates/header.html** with following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="testing" th:fragment="header">
      2016 Header
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have **templates/index.html** with following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
</head>

<body>


    <div th:insert="header :: header"></div>
    <h3>User Registration</h3>
    <form action="/AddUser" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="lname" placeholder="Firstname"
            required /> <input type="text" name="lname" id="fname"
            placeholder="Lastname" required />
        <button type="submit">Insert</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting **2016 Header** in index.html. But, nothing is getting displayed.

I am using following configuration in my gradle dependencies

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
```

Please tell me where i am going wrong.

Comment: Which version of thymeleaf do you use? Most likely you are using a version in which `th:insert` is not included. Alternatively, you could try `th:replace` or `th:include` instead of `th:insert`.

Comment: For your information only, `th:insert` has been introduced in Thymeleaf 3.0.